# Parsing datetime strings with microseconds in Python 2.5

Tags: python, datetime, parsing, python-2.5

I have a text file with a lot of datetime strings in isoformat. The strings are similar to this:

```
'2009-02-10 16:06:52.598800'
```

These strings were generated using `str(datetime_object)`. The problem is that, for some reason, `str(datetime_object)` generates a different format when the datetime object has microseconds set to zero and some strings look like this:

```
'2009-02-10 16:06:52'
```

How can I parse these strings and convert them into a [datetime object](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)?

It's very important to get all the data in the object, including microseconds.

NOTE: I have to use **Python 2.5**, the format directive `%f` for microseconds doesn't exist in 2.5.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
from datetime import datetime

def str2datetime(s):
    parts = s.split('.')
    dt = datetime.strptime(parts[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return dt.replace(microsecond=int(parts[1]))
```

Using `strptime` itself to parse the date/time string (so no need to think up corner cases for a regex).

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I'd suggest to change the last line to:
return dt.replace(microsecond=int(1000 * float( '0.' + parts[1])))

this handles all cases correctly, like e.g. 
'2017-03-16 21:20:57.31'
which should give 310us rather than 31us.

Answer (score 11):

Use the dateutil module.  It supports a much wider range of date and time formats than the built in Python ones.

You'll need to **easy_install dateutil** for the following code to work:

```
from dateutil.parser import parser

p = parser()
datetime_with_microseconds = p.parse('2009-02-10 16:06:52.598800')
print datetime_with_microseconds.microsecond
```

results in:

```
598799
```

Answer (score 5):

Someone has already filed a  bug with this issue: [Issue 1982](http://bugs.python.org/issue1982). Since you need this to work with python 2.5 you must parse the value manualy and then manipulate the datetime object.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the best solution, but you can use a regular expression:

```
m = re.match(r'(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(?:\.(\d{6}))?', datestr)
dt = datetime.datetime(*[int(x) for x in m.groups() if x])
```