# How to convert string date to dateobject and get the year when string date value is in format 2021-01-22T11:36:52.387000+01:00 with datetime?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I tried this:

```
 timestamp = "2021-01-22T11:36:52.387000+01:00"
 timestampObject = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

But gave me error:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains: .150000+01:00

What is the rest reprisenting and how do I convert the rest? Also  what does the 'T' mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
timestampObject = datetime.fromisoformat(
 "2021-01-22T11:36:52.387000+01:00" ).date()

 print('timestampObject.year: ', timestampObject.year)
```

> timestampObject.year: 2021

Answer (score 1):

Because you also have to **supply a format specifier to take care of the trailing microseconds and timezone specifier**, like the error is telling you, see [Conversion of datetime string with microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531157/parsing-datetime-strings-with-microseconds) and [...milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31096353/202229). Probably you need `'.fZ'`. See the datetime doc.

Also, the 'T' just stands for 'Time'; it separates the date-field from the time-field, for ease in parsing (with sed/perl/grep/regex/etc.). Makes it easy if you wanted to a) locate datetimes within a log or b) throw away/separate the time part from the date part.

Comment: The timestamp is an iso formatted string, any format specifiers would be redundant when you can just call 'fromisoformat'

Comment: @Boskosnitch: oh ok, didn't know ISO included microseconds. Is it guaranteed to handle all timezone specifiers?

Comment: whats the differene with this format 2018-04-19T00:00:00+02:00 and the other one? datetime.fromisoformat does not work on this fromat. It says "argument must be str"

Answer (score 1):

The string format you have is actually a datetime in ISO format. Luckily datetime has a function for handling that, you don't have to worry about supplying a format specifier for the trailing time objects...

Do you want only the date?

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2021-01-22T11:36:52.387000+01:00").date()
datetime.date(2021, 1, 22)
```

Or do you want datetime?

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2021-01-22T11:36:52.387000+01:00")
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 22, 11, 36, 52, 387000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but It worked only when I removed the first datetime. I dont know if that was a typo or if its because i am using python3, but thanks for help :)

Comment: whats the differene with this format 2018-04-19T00:00:00+02:00 and the other one?  datetime.fromisoformat does not work on this fromat. It says "argument must be str"